# When I merge 2 github accs(private and prof), do I retain the permissions and contributions from the private repositories of my organisation?

Tags: github

I am currently contributing to my work private repo via my professional github account. If I merge my professional account to my personal account, deleting my professional github account, will the contributions that I made to the work private repos reflect in my personal account and will I still have the permission to the work private repos?